# Detect with Javascript when a elelment has recieved content

Tags: javascript, ajax

When is clicked, div with id **button** makes a AJAX request and adds new content inside div with id **newContent**.

I am trying to launch a function, after the the div **button** get's clicks and the div with id **newContent** receives the content.

```
<div id="button"> </div>
<div id="newContent"></div>
```

Unfortunatelly I can't make changes to the .js file, that contains the AJAX function.

I didn't succed with:

```
var contentdiv = document.getElementById('newContent');

window.onload = function() {
    contentdiv.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (contentdiv.readyState == "interactive") {
           myFunction();
        } 
    }
}
```

What could I do, to launch my function after the content has successfully added to the newContent div?

Comment: @Ananth *"Unfortunatelly I can't make changes to the .js file, that contains the AJAX function"*

Comment: You need a mutation observer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For modern browsers I would recommend *mutation observers*:

```
        var observer = new MutationObserver( myFunction );
        // configuration of the observer:
        var config = { attributes: false, childList: true, characterData: true, subtree: true };

        // pass in the target node, as well as the observer options
        observer.observe(contentDiv, config);
```

This adds a mutation observer to your element. You can configure the options to which the observer needs to listen. *Jquery* doesn't support this natively (yet). This will fire when there is content added to the `contentDiv`. Or changes to the child elements in the `contentDiv`.

> - **childList** Set to true if additions and removals of the target node's child elements (including text nodes) are to be observed.
>     attributes Set to true if mutations to target's attributes are to be observed.
> - **characterData** Set to true if mutations to target's data are to be observed.
> - **subtree** Set to true if mutations to not just target, but also target's descendants are to be observed.
> - **attributeOldValue** Set to true if attributes is set to true and target's attribute value before the mutation needs to be recorded.
> - **characterDataOldValue** Set to true if characterData is set to true and target's data before the mutation needs to be recorded.
> - **attributeFilter** Set to an array of attribute local names (without namespace) if not all attribute mutations need to be observed.
>
> *Source: MDN*

Which browsers support this: [CanIuse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=mutationobserver)

Read more here: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver)

`MutationObserver` is a powerful tool. It also provides information about the changes in the element. I suggest to read up with the possibilities. For now it will do the thing you want.

> As a fall back for IE9 and 10 you can use:

```
contentDiv.addEventListener ('DOMNodeInserted', myFunction, false);
```

This, however, will not host the same functionality as the *mutation observer* and its use is discouraged by MDN.

Comment: @Marian07 - Per the "CanIuse" link, just keep in mind that this technique requires IE 11 or greater.

Answer (score 1):

Another way, you can use the `setInterval` function and checked every X millisecond your content div.

```
var oldString = document.getElementById("DivId").innerHTML;
var checkContentDiv = setInterval(function() {
   if(document.getElementById("DivId").innerHTML != oldString) {
     //your div is updated.
     clearInterval(checkContentDiv);
   }
}, 500);
```

Comment: This is a nice cross-browser technique. Thank you!